# Name for board/table with numbers increasing from central region

Tags: numbers

I have a "board" which is divided into N regions.

Region 1 occupies the 4 central cells of the board. Each further region contains all cells that are horizontally, vertically or diagonally adjacent to cells of the previous region, and do not belong to any of the previous regions.

For example, when N = 4, here is how the regions look:

```
44444444
43333334
43222234
43211234
43211234
43222234
43333334
44444444
```

Is there a name for a board/table which is laid out like this?